# How to get the return type of a method call in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, return-type

Normally you would expect just hovering over a method it would show a popup of the return type.

How do you get this information in intellij ultimate?

Answer (score 39):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (or <kbd>⌃J</kbd> on Mac) when cursor is on a method declaration or call. It will show you the pop-up you want. As a bonus: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> will display method body as well in a pop-up.

Comment: i'm on a mac, is that windows?

Comment: @user1361315: I am not a Mac user, but typically you can replace Ctrl with Cmd on Mac.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz **⌘Q** will kill the app. It's better to consult the [keymap reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf). "Quick documentation lookup" is **^J**

Comment: @millimoose: +1, thanks, I fixed my answer, but the credit should go to you!

Comment: Is there any way to show the current binding for generics parameters, too? Eclipse does it by automatically and helps a lot.

Comment: CTRL-Q just shows javadoc for method. To show **inferred** return type see @ScottShamus answer.

Answer (score 38):

You hover it and hold down CTRL in windows or CMD in Mac

Comment: It might be just my machine, but I had to hover over the method, press control, and move my mouse slightly to get this to work

Comment: @EvanParsons I usually press and hold CMD before I actually mouse over the symbol. That does it first time, every time. If I hover over it before, I also have to move my mouse slightly to get it to register.

Answer (score 5):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for quick definition
Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> may help

Answer (score 1):

In intellij, Go to Help > Productivity Guide
you will find a list of useful shortcuts to increase productivity

Regarding, this question in mac Press option+command+V to get the list of names that you can choose [image]

Ctrl+ J in mac for getting the documentation

Find screenshots for ease:-

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Shift+P` works great with extra bonus by highlighting relevant return expression (IntelliJ 2020.2.3 CE)

Answer (score 0):

Hot key for that: Ctrl + Shift + P
Toolbar: "View->Type Info"